# HTTPS 301 redirecting to http version

Tags: url, url-rewrite, redirect, https, 301-redirect

> We have implemented https on our Magento store a few months back and
>   everything seems fine exceptive noted that the server response for 301
>   redirects don't seem to be honoring the https://
>
> The server response is similar to this.

---

> Location:
>       http://www.example.com
>
> Redirecting to: http://www.example.com

---

> This is then leading critters to HTTP versions of the page then a 301
>   to the https version, creating a loop.
>
> Is this correct or is something wrong causing the server to output
>   http and not https?

Answer (score 0):

Change both admin panel URL in https version.

```
web/unsecure/base_url

web/secure/base_url
```

and place below code in htacess

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC] RewriteRule (.*)
>   https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

So all crawl URL will redirect to https URL.

Comment: Hi, I have already done this but it still keeps showing as http in the htaccess 301 redirects

Comment: not getting you. Please clarify more.

Comment: Hi Have already added the htacces code and changed base urls but still when we use htaccess to 301 redirect URLs it redirects to the http versions of the page and not https.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by setting the cookie setting in the backend of magento and this fixed my issue.